# Snowflake Java UDF using BigInteger returning indeterministic results

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, biginteger

I created a Java UDF in Snowflake which takes in a bigint in SQL using a BigInteger in Java, then returns it as a string.

```
create or replace function pass_through_print(divisor bigint) 
returns string 
language java 
handler='TestClass.pass_through_print'
as $$
import java.math.*;
class TestClass {
  public static String pass_through_print(BigInteger divisor) {
      return divisor.toString();
  }
}
$$;
```

I then ran the following tests

## Test 1 (works as expected)

```
select pass_through_val, count(*)
from (
    select
    pass_through_print(9) as pass_through_val
    from (
        select seq8() as val
        from table(generator(rowcount => 100000))
      )
  )
group by pass_through_val
```

Results (Works as expected)

```
PASS_THROUGH_VAL    COUNT(*)
9           100,000
```

## Test 2 (indeterministic)

```
select pass_through_val, count(*)
from (
    select
    case
        when val % 2 = 0 then null
        else pass_through_print(9)
    end as pass_through_val
    from (
        select seq8() as val
        from table(generator(rowcount => 100000))
      )
  )
group by pass_through_val
```

### Expected Result

```
PASS_THROUGH_VAL    COUNT(*)
null    50,000
9       50,000
```

### Actual results from multiple runs

The pass through result changes randomly.

```
PASS_THROUGH_VAL    COUNT(*)
null            50,000
-25             50,000
```

```
PASS_THROUGH_VAL    COUNT(*)
null            50,000
-1              50,000
```

```
PASS_THROUGH_VAL    COUNT(*)
null            50,000
95              50,000
```

Changing BigInteger to int in the Java UDF works as expected for all tests

```
create or replace function pass_through_int_print(val int) 
returns string 
language java 
handler='TestClass.pass_through_int_print'
as $$
import java.math.*;
class TestClass {
  public static String pass_through_int_print(int val) {
      return String.valueOf(val);
  }
}
$$;
```

It seems like the case statement in combination with BigInteger conversion is causing things to break. Does anyone know what could be happening?

**UPDATE**
Even weirder behaviour is that if I call `pass_through_print` outside of the case statement, it works as expected, and it also makes the one inside the case statement work too.

#### New Test

```
select pass_through_val_correct, pass_through_val, count(*)
from (
    select
    pass_through_print(123) as pass_through_val_correct, -- added this line
    case
        when val % 2 = 0 then null
        else pass_through_print(9)
    end as pass_through_val
    from (
        select seq8() as val
        from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000))
      )
  )
group by pass_through_val_correct, pass_through_val
```

Result

```
PASS_THROUGH_VAL_CORRECT    PASS_THROUGH_VAL    COUNT(*)
123 null    500,000
123 9       500,000
```

Comment: BigInteger is an arbitrary-precision numeric type. It has no analog data type in Snowflake. You can pass values in and out using String. I have a BigInteger UDF library written in JavaScript that does that https://github.com/GregPavlik/SnowflakeUDFs/tree/main/BigIntegerMath.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the query (and call pass_through_print outside of the case statement), the execution plan changes, and the function is executed in a stand-alone operation (ExtensionFunction), but in your original query, the function is defined as a volatile function and executed as a part of the projection operation (which is a sub-step of Aggregation).

[image: execution plans]

Somehow calling the function as part of the projection step prevents processing BigInteger (maybe there could be other libraries impacted). Please submit a case to Snowflake support. This looks like a bug.